# How to select the third and subsequent elements in the array in javascript

Tags: javascript

For example I have an array like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` , and I want to select `[3, 4, 5]`.

Is there a simple way to do that? Lots of thanks.

Comment: [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slicing for this.

Lets say `x = [1,2,3,4,5]`. Just do `s.slice(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple `for` loop and begin looping at the `nth` element of the array.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for (let i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i])
}
```